# Simple Javascript function returning undefined value

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I have a simple `JavaScript` function, which I am trying to get the ID of the element I used to initiate the function.  My element is a simple `DIV` :

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function updateProduct(prod_id,old_q){
        alert(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
    }   
</script>

<div id="button_container" style="float:left; margin-right:7px; margin-top:3px;  width:59px; height:20px; cursor:pointer;" onClick="updateProduct('19','3060');">
```

There are other HTML elements on this page (of course), but this is a test button for now, and no other elements have the same test ID I have here called `button_container`.  Also my `Script` is stand alone just as you see.  It's not part of a longer `Script` etc..  Am I missing something super simple?  The alert returns "Undefined" and the `Console` doesn't report any warnings or errors...

Comment: what is jQuery(this) refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` in your function is the global object `window`.

You need to pass it to the function.

```
function updateProduct(prod_id,old_q, element){
    alert(element.id);
}   

<div id="button_container"  onClick="updateProduct('19','3060', this);">
```

Comment: +++  Thanks!  Worked perfectly!  Will accept in 7 minutes, lol

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the element object.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function updateProduct(obj, prod_id,old_q){
      alert(jQuery(obj).attr('id'));
     }   
</script>
<div id="button_container" style="float:left; margin-right:7px; margin-top:3px;  width:59px; height:20px; cursor:pointer;" onClick="updateProduct(this, '19','3060');">
```